# \Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\AsciiSlugger implementing \Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface?

Tags: string, symfony

I'm trying to use the `\Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\AsciiSlugger` class - from the "symfony/string" package - to sanitize a string. This class implements two interfaces: `\Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface` and `\Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface`. The latter comes from the "symfony/translation-contracts" package. However in the "symfony/string" composer.json file, "symfony/translation-contracts" is in the "require-dev" section and not the "require" section. How is that supposed to work on a live system, where you are not meant to load the "dev" dependencies?

Comment: You could include the packages yourself? If you think it is a bug in their dependencies you should report it on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, that what I did to avoid staying stuck. I thought I would ask before reporting a bug, to be on the safe side. Thanks.